# How to add web element names in android scroll view into an ArrayList using Appium Java?

Tags: java, android, automation, uiscrollview, appium

I have a element list inside a scroll view in android. I need to add all the element names into a ArrayList. I have tried many ways of scrolling and none of them fulfill my requirement. Please help me to achieve this.

This is the class name of the element list: `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`
This is the id of each element: `com.testapp.poker:id/recyclerViewCards`

```
List <String> elementNameList = new ArrayList();

    public void getWebElementsNameList(String classNameOfElementList, String elementId){
            System.out.println("Items found:");
            Gauge.writeMessage("Items found:");
            int i = 1;
            for(WebElement element : getWebElements(classNameOfElementList, elementId)) {
                System.out.println(i + ") " + element.getText());
                Gauge.writeMessage(i + ") " + element.getText());
                elementNameList.add(element.getText());
                i++;
            }
        }
```

The above code will only grabs the elements which are visible on the current view. I need some help to modify this with the scrolling logic.

Comment: Do you truly need all the elements to be in the list or are you looking to do something else? Perhaps click on one of them?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. UIAutomator can return the elements which are visible. Unlike selenium, appium(UiAutomator) can not see the elements which are not visible on the screen.

Solution to your problem is : 
Get visible elements and add them to arraylist, then scroll to next elements and add to the arraylist and so on until the list ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
 List <String> elementNameList = new ArrayList();

public void getWebElementsNameList(String classNameOfElementList, String elementId){
    nameStart = "";
    System.out.println("Items found:");
    Gauge.writeMessage("Items found:");
    int i = 1;
    while(true){    
        for(WebElement element : getWebElements(classNameOfElementList, elementId)) {
            System.out.println(i + ") " + element.getText());
            Gauge.writeMessage(i + ") " + element.getText());
            elementNameList.add(element.getText());
            i++;
        }
        if (!keepSwipping()) {
        break;
        }
    }
}

private static String nameStart = "";

private boolean keepSwipping() {
    if (isElementPresent(By.xpath(FIRST_ELEMENT_XPATH)) && isElementPresent(By.xpath(LAST_ELEMENT_XPATH))) {
        AndroidElement firstElement = (AndroidElement) driver.findElementByXPath(FIRST_ELEMENT_XPATH);
        AndroidElement lastElement= (AndroidElement) driver.findElementByXPath(LAST_ELEMENT_XPATH);
        if (nameStart.equals(firstElement.getText())) {
            return false;
        } else {
            nameStart = firstElement.getText();
            swipe(lastElement.getLocation().x, lastElement.getLocation().y, firstElement.getLocation().x,
                    firstElement.getLocation().y, 2000);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```